# How would you format the following line so that it fits under 100 chars?

Tags: python, pep8

I need to make this line fit in under 100 chars, and make it as PEP8 compliant (except for the 80 char limit) as possible:

```
date = dateparser.parse(parsed_response["creation_time"]) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=parsed_response["time"])
```

How would you do it? Adding parenthesis and dividing it in two lines seems to make it look bad in my opinion.

Comment: Break the two arguments into two temporary variable assignments?

Comment: Extract to variables?

Comment: There is also "Google Python Style Guide" worth reading as an addition to PEP8.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the obvious approach would be to introduce variables for `dateparser.parse(parsed_response["creation_time"])` and `datetime.timedelta(minutes=parsed_response["time"])`. That would have the pleasant side effect of making it more clear just what the heck that code is doing, particularly if you took the opportunity to give the variables more descriptive names than "date".

Answer (score 1):

You could just break your line as follows:

```
date = dateparser.parse(parsed_response["creation_time"]) + \
       datetime.timedelta(minutes=parsed_response["time"])
```

But preparing variables before, then just adding them would be more readable.

```
creation_time = dateparser.parse(parsed_response["creation_time"])
parsed_response_time = datetime.timedelta(minutes=parsed_response["time"])

date = creation_time + parsed_response_time
```

Comment: Right aligning the lower line will make it look nicer

Answer (score 0):

My solution to that would be something like this:

```
creation_time = dateparser.parse(parsed_response["creation_time"])
time_delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=parsed_response["time"])
date = creation_time + time_delta
```

That way you got it PEP8 compliant and you got those 2 variables you can reuse for some other purpose without fetching and parsing again.